# I dont't understand boolean in ruby

Tags: ruby

My code, in my file spec

```
describe TestChamber::Account_v1 do
    let(:agree) { nil }
    let(:agree) { nil }

    let(:account) do
    TestChamber::Account_v1.new(
      :agree => agree,
      :agree1 => agree
    )
  end

    context "when tested account v1" do
    let(:agree) {true}
    let(:agree1) {false}
    it "test account" do
      account.create_account
    end
  end
```

my file lib i get two argument then puts them in terminal

```
   def initialize(options={})
      @agree = options[:@agree]
      @agree1 = options[:@agree1]
    end
    def create_account
          if (@agree == true)
            puts "abc"
          end
      if (@agree1 != false)
        puts "abc1"
      end
   end
```

my output

```
abc1
```

anyone can explain for me this code?

Comment: what is `@agree`, where does it come from and how is it related to `:agree` and `:agree1`?

Comment: @Stefan wish I could upvote your comment more than once :P

Comment: You have defined `let(:agree) {true}` and it should be accessible with `agree` with-in your specs not the code inside lib. Can you post exactly which part of your spec failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting:

```
@agree = options[:@agree]
@agree1 = options[:@agree1]
```

Replacing this with:

```
@agree = options[:agree]
@agree1 = options[:agree1]
```

should fix the assignment problem.

Futhermore, in you spec file there's:

```
let(:agree) { nil }
let(:agree) { nil }
```

The second one should probably be `agree1`. And further down:

```
TestChamber::Account_v1.new(
  :agree => agree,
  :agree1 => agree
)
```

Again, this should be `:agree1 => agree1`

Comment: i had been set let(:agree) {true}

Comment: The other `let(:agree) {true}` and `let(:agree1) {false}` takes the priority inside the `context` so ideally  `@agree` should be true and `@agree1` should be false. Something else's happening in his code.

Comment: i replced but i got output abc abc1 agree1 is true but i had been set it is false

Comment: @beginerdeveloper updated my answer, you should use better variable names.